# Octave: How would I display e in binary + decimal representation?

Tags: binary, decimal, octave

I need to show the user the value of `e` in both of the forms above, but I'm new to computer programming/octave.

binary: not sure if there is a function to convert `e` to binary, but my guess would be `e`=`10.1011011111100001010...`

decimal: `e`=`1*2^1.??` <- not sure how to display the 7 after the decimal point.

Comment: Decimal representation of e is 2.7183, but I guess that is not what you are looking for. What is it then?

Comment: @bogl hmmm....maybe I have my terminology mixed up. I wanted the decimal expansion

Comment: For decimal don't you just want `exp(1)`?

Comment: Decimal expansion and decimal representation are IMHO synonym.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The decimal expansion of *e* is:

`e = 2*10^0 + 7*10^-1 + 1*10^-2 + 8*10^-3 + 3*10^-4 + ... =  2.7183 + ...`

In Octave you may get the decimal representation like this

```
>> e
ans =  2.7183
```

and the binary representation like that

```
>> p=20; dec2bin(floor(e*2^p))
ans = 1010110111111000010101
```

*p* is the number of digits required after the point. When displaying the final result, the point needs to be inserted in front of the *p*-th digit from the right: `e = 10.10110111111000010101 (base-2)`.